# Why is my cloned HTML5 canvas element's content displaying as a solid black background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a large canvas element which I want to clone and display inside a new smaller canvas element to serve as a miniature display after the webpage is loaded.

I've created the new smaller blank canvas element ahead of time and have appended it to the DOM with a specific height/width.

The idea was to clone the large canvas element into the smaller one after the page is loaded using:

```
//grab the context from your destination canvas
const destCtx = destinationCanvas.getContext('2d');

//call its drawImage() function passing it the source canvas directly
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```

However, all that is being displayed is a solid black background. My expectation is that the smaller canvas should now display a duplicate design of the larger canvas, just in a smaller sized area.

I've looked around a bit, but have not found a working solution to the issue as of yet.

A little sketch of what i'm trying to do:
[image]

Also tried the following:

```
const smallCanvas = document.getElementById('smallCanvas'); 
const bigCanvas = document.getElementById('bigCanvas'); 

smallCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bigCanvas, 0, 0, bigCanvas.width, bigCanvas.height, 0, 0, smallCanvas.width, smallCanvas.height);
```

The result always looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Assuming sourceCanvas is an `HTMLCanvasElement`, the issue isn't in your code snippet so any answers will be a guess

Comment: `sourceCanvas` would have to be an Image DOM Object like: `var sourceCanvas = document.createElement('img'); sourceCanvas.onload = function(){ destCtx.drawImage(this, 0, 0); }; sourceCanvas.src = 'yourImage.png';`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you didn't pass any parameters to the **drawImage()** method except for the source and the position. In this case it will draw the image 1:1 onto the smaller canvas - which means you just see a fraction of your source canvas up to the dimensions of the small canvas.

To fix this you need to specify two rectangles (x, y, width, height) - the first being the values from the bigger and the second from the smaller.
e.g. `drawImage(source,sourceX,sourceY,sourceWidth,sourceHeight,targetX,targetY,targetWidth,targetHeight);`

Here's an example:

```js
var bigCanvas = document.getElementById("bigCanvas");
var smallCanvas = document.getElementById("smallCanvas");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  bigCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  smallCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bigCanvas, 0, 0, bigCanvas.width, bigCanvas.height, 0, 0, smallCanvas.width, smallCanvas.height);
}
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/16/400/300";
```

```html
<canvas id="bigCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="smallCanvas" width="40" height="30"></canvas>
```

Comment: what if I'm trying to apply this as a general feature and the bigCanvas width/height change based on whichever canvas design I'm viewing? (so I don't have a set width/height for the source canvas). The smaller canvas I can set it as a static height/width of say 150px.

Comment: In my example above you can replace `this.width, this.height` inside the drawImage function with the dimensions of your canvas element - looking back at the code from your question it's probably `sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm still getting a solid black square.   

I basically did the following:    

Created a mini blank canvas ahead of time with a set height/width and appended to the dom on top of the source Canvas.  

`const smallCanvas = document.getElementById('smallCanvas');  
const bigCanvas = document.getElementById('bigCanvas');  
smallCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bigCanvas, 0, 0, bigCanvas.width, bigCanvas.height, 0, 0, smallCanvas.width, smallCanvas.height);` . 

When applied, the box just fills up again in with solid black instead of displaying the image from the sourceCanvas.

Comment: No errors in the console? I'm afraid you'll have to update your question with a running example of your code so I can see what's going on.

Comment: What is the content of your big canvas you want to draw? Did you draw images onto using drawImage? In this case at the moment of cloning they might not have been drawn to the big canvas yet. Unfortunately I just can guess if you don't post a working example. =)